# Reduce Vertical gap between composite in FillLayout

Tags: java, layout, swt

I have created a composite A with two composites B and C. 
A is FillLayout.
B and C are composites of GridLayout.
I see a huge gap between B and C inside A.
How can I reduce it?

[image]

The gap between Wait for typing and Image format should reduce.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your code. Ideally an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

That is what `FillLayout` does, it fills the given area spacing out the controls to fit evenly. It doesn't have any parameters to control this.

If you want more control use a different layout such as `GridLayout`.

Comment: I use filllayout because content fits the given screen size perfectly when I resize. Now i dont need scroll bars to see the content. they are small and perfectly fit. My only issue now is this space! :(

Comment: It doesn't matter why you use it, you can't change this behavior. You will have to use another layout if you don't want the even spacing. Perhaps if you edit your question to explain exactly what the problem with other layouts is we may be able to help.